# Compressing a sequence of numeric datas

Tags: math, compression, integer-arithmetic

There are 10 numeric values each value will be within range of 1 - 4096.
These numeric values can also be duplicate. The aim is to compress this 10 numeric values in 24bits. But the compression should be lossless and from resultant 24bits we should also retrieve 10 numeric values with its original sequence.

Could any one help me with some suggestions!

Comment: You can not compress a random sequence of 120 bit to 24 bit. You would need some usable structure between the 10 numbers that reduces the possible/admissible configurations from 2^120 to less than 2^24.

Comment: Than what could be the minimum possible bit in which this could be compressed.

Comment: Without further information, there is none. With 24 bit you can address a set of 2^24 ~ 1.68e+07 elements, compression is the reverse map of this. 10 numbers of 12bit gives a set of 2^120 ~ 1.33e+36 combinations, which is vastly too much.

Comment: I understand that it is nearly impossible but there should be some way out, basically my aim is to encode 10 numbers in a single color value of 24-bit.

Comment: This is called a "hash", which is not lossless but with a proper algorithm will have an even distribution of duplicates.

Comment: *if* there are a lot of duplicates then something like run length encoding could work in specific cases. The claim isn't that you can never compress 10 numbers in the given range into 24 bits, but that there is no general-purpose algorithm that will always do so for all input. If the total number of vectors of length 10 that you seek to encode is < 2^24 then you could come up with a custom loss-less encoding scheme that will work for those numbers, though it might be terribly as-hoc (e.g. essentially a look-up table,)